# How to create a active Link for web using expo-router?

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-router

I am learning expo router trying to use it in a web project. I am trying to style current active link in header Bar Menu. I am looking for something like <[NavLink> in case of react-router](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/nav-link) but don't find something similar in [expo-router docs.](https://docs.expo.dev/routing/introduction/)

```
<Link href={"/home"}>Home</Link>
<Link href={"/about"}>About</Link>
<Link href={"/product"}>Product</Link>
```

How to style the active link in case of expo-router particularly for web.

Comment: I ended up using Tabs Instead https://docs.expo.dev/router/advanced/tabs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `usePathname` hook to get the current URL and compare it to the link's href

```
const NavLink = ({ href, styles, ...props }) => {
  const path = usePathname();

  return (
    <Link href={href} styles={styles({ isActive: href === path })} {...props} />
  );
}
```